# Get the PHP error log from PHP on remote hosting

Tags: php, logging, error-handling

Is there a PHP function or some other way of obtaining the PHP error log as a string?

I need this because I cannot access the error log of a site I am running on someone else's server. - He offered to email me the error log, but that isn't exactly convenient.

Is there some way I could output the error log to a PHP page?

---

I realize that viewing the entire server's error log is not really going to happen for me. However, I know you can do something like this to email a manual `error_log` call to yourself:

```
error_log('A really bad error', 3, 'me@myemail.com');
```

Is it possible to configure a page to email errors to you instead of displaying them?

Comment: Not a very good solution..., but when you know the path to the error log file you can get it's contents with `file_get_contents`.

Comment: See [error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) php.ini setting.

Comment: For locating the PHP error log, the canonical is *[Where does PHP store the error log? (PHP 5, Apache, FastCGI, and cPanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/)* (despite the over-specific title).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a badly secured server, yes. But on most servers there are two users: apache and [ you ]. You don't have access to the server logs, since they are owned by the apache user (or whichever server you're using).

However, you could probably try it:

```
echo file_get_contents('/var/log/httpd/error_log');
```

*Note: that's the default location on a RedHat-based apache server. It may be different*

**Update** *To reflect the updated question*
No, you cannot view the error log with `error_log` - it is a one-way process that gets handled by the webserver. It only writes the log, but you cannot read it.

You can probably display the errors with this:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You could even use [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to handle all warnings and notices (for example, to mail them). But that's pretty much all you can do.

Comment: Hi, I'm on a debian server - just tried that but got "operation not permitted"

Comment: Then it's a properly secured server ;-) Just get the man to mail you the logs.

Comment: OK, do you think you could take a look at my updated question?

Comment: excellent thanks, I think I'll use `set_error_hanlder` - the reason I want this is it's for a web service for an app I'm about to submit to Apple, and if the service goes down anytime between when I submit the app and Apple approves it I need to know straight away - cheers.

Comment: Another common location is `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. A canonical is not easy to find, but it may be *[Find out the error_log's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955411/find-out-the-error-logs-path)* (though not maintained / kept up-to-date).