# Find out the error_log's path

Tags: php, apache

I have this `domain.com` pointed to `/home/username/public_html/domain.com`.

I added these lines to the *.htaccess* file:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /oohps.php
ErrorDocument 404 /where.php
```

So I can show some styled template.

The problem is that when trying to access a nonexisting page, I get an additional internal server error, so these files are not opened.

I wanted to check for the logs, but I cannot find the error log in that path (`/home/username/public_html/domain.com`).

I found one in `/var/log/httpd`, but I don't think it’s the right folder, because there are many errors not involved with this page and I didn't see any involved.

Is there a PHP function that would **output the errors log file path**?

Comment: The canonical is *[Where does PHP store the error log? (PHP 5, Apache, FastCGI, and cPanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/)* (despite the over-specific title).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An internal server error has often something to do with [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) and */var/log/httpd/* is the error log file of Apache, so I think you are in the right file.

---

The error path is set in *php.ini*. To get the path use [`ini_get()`](http://php.net/ini_get):

```
<?php
  $errorPath = ini_get('error_log');
?>
```

Comment: Re *"/var/log/httpd/ is the error log file of Apache"*: Isn't that a directory/folder, not a file? (The Apache error log file may also be `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.)

Answer (score 6):

To only get the path where PHP stores its logs, use:

```
pathinfo(ini_get('error_log'),PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
```

Which should return something like this (on localhost):

```
/Applications/MAMP/logs
```

Comment: just curious, why not just `dirname(ini_get('error_log'))`, just wondering if theres a difference

Answer (score 2):

Check for the `error_log` setting in file `php.ini` (or in the output of function [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)).

Answer (score 2):

As I stumbled upon this problem and ini_get() didn’t help, the following might be a solution for someone else too.

In case *error_log* is not set in file *php.ini* or the like, the error is sent to the [SAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Application_Programming_Interface) error logger. This, in case of e.g. Apache 2, is the error log defined in the Apache `vhost` configuration. A way to get the Apache log directory would be to check the symlink value of the standard error file descriptor.

An example which works on Linux would be:

```
$logdir = \pathinfo(\realpath('/proc/'.\getmypid().'/fd/2'), PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
```

or if `getmypid()` is not available

```
$logdir = \pathinfo(\realpath('/proc/self/fd/2'), PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
```

This example reads the path of the symlinked file of */proc/[PID]/fd/2* which is the standard error file descriptor.

Comment: Would this work on shared hosting, with reduced permissions? Or is it the sort of thing that would return an error because they don't allow getting pids?

Comment: I don't know for sure. But it's correct that you can disable php functions using the php.ini configuration and thus some hosters might also disable `getmypid()`. So i think the correct answer would be: it depends on the hoster - give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such a function, but maybe [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) will have some information about that.

Log paths are defined inside an Apache site's configuration file. If you want a custom path to it, if not by default, all the logs are loaded into /var/log/apache2/*.log, so PHP has nothing to do with it.