# Where is the error_log file?

Tags: php, error-log

I already set

```
// Don't display errors
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
// Write errors to log
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
// Error log file name
ini_set('log_errors', '/var/log/php/error.log');
```

but I cannot find the log file.

I also checked the *php.ini* file, but there isn't any error log. I cannot find directory named `var/log/apache` or `var/log/php`.

I'm trying to *log* the errors into a file, without showing it in the browser.

The problem:

1. I don't see the `/var/log/` directory. Instead, I found the `/php/logs/` directory.
2. I cannot log the errors without showing it on browser, even after I use the `ini_set()` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out the error\_log's path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955411/find-out-the-error-logs-path)

Comment: The canonical is *[Where does PHP store the error log? (PHP 5, Apache, FastCGI, and cPanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/)* (despite the over-specific title).

Answer (score 1):

Try

`\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`

where *xampp* is your installation folder.

If you haven't changed the *error_log* setting in PHP (check with [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)), it will be logged to the Apache log.

Comment: alright I got it. but the error is not logged in the file why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You should have written `ini_set('error_log','/var/log/php/error.log')` not `ini_set('log_errors', '/var/log/php/error.log')`