# PHP session not resetting on login following a timeout

Tags: php, session

I have the following code at the top every page:

FROM "PROCESS-LOGIN.PHP"

```
session_start();


$login_query
    = ("select * from members where email = '$email' and  password = '$password'");
$login_result = mysqli_query($link, $login_query);
$hits = mysqli_affected_rows($link);

if ($hits != 1)
{
    echo "Invalid username and password combination ";
};

while ($db_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login_result))
{
    ;
    $id = $db_result['id'];
    $membertype = $db_result['memberType'];

    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

FROM "SESSION.PHP"

```
session_start();
if ( isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $userID = $_SESSION['id'];

    $session_query = ("select * from members where id = '$userID'");
    $session_result = mysqli_query($link, $session_query);

    while ($db_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($session_result)) {

        $email = $db_result['email'];
        $membertype = $db_result['memberType'];

        // various other things set from the DB

    };

    if ($membertype == 1){
        $home = "/view/cook-dashboard.php";
    } else if ($membertype == 2) {
        $home = "/view/customer-dashboard.php";
    } else if ($membertype == 3) {
        $home = "/view/admin/dashboard.php";
    };


} else {$membertype = "xxx"; $userID = 0;};
```

At the top of certain pages I check for $membertype, here is an example of that code:

```
if ($membertype != 99){
    die("You're session has timed out. Please <a href='/view/login.php'>login again</a>");
}
```

If I log in to the web app I am taken to the page with the above check and all is fine. If I come back several hours later then I get the "You're session has timed out" message. If I output the variables it shows $membertype as "xxx" - which is what is set if $_SESSION['id'] is not set.

So far, to me, this all makes sense.

What's puzzling me is that if I log in then $membertype is still "xxx" and that page still fails.

Comment: Where do you set your session value `$_SESSION['id']` ?

Comment: check your ini files and caching and that the session was started in all files while checking if the session array is indeed set/not empty.

Comment: Sorry but I would rewrite your entire code base. Why do you wrap variables in brackets? Why do you use `SELECT *`? why do you trail everything with `;`? etc.

Comment: @Martin the code base is going to be re-written completely. This is a prototype. I can program, and write fairly extensive and functioning applications, but I wouldn't call myself a software developer. I know that I have bad practices and my code isn't the best. When it comes time to write this app for real, if it proves to be valuable, then I have real developers who will do it.

Comment: Is there more code above this? I see a database query but no code that connects to the database...

Comment: My guess is that you're setting your $_SESSION['id'] in code that occurs after your above code, so the "timeout" code is being hit before the login attempt, which sets the member type to xxx.

Comment: Updated to show the code before the code I posted. @Martin Setting $_SESSION['id'] in the login process.

Comment: Can you exaplain which pages get called when? when is `session.php` called? in relation to `process-login.php`? Is session.php a header file in each PHP page ?

Comment: @Martin - yes it is. Process-login happens when the user logs in (obviously) it then passes the user onto their dashboard. Every page as session.php as an include at the top. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a host of issues wrong with your code. It may work (or not) but falls short of best practise and so errors such as this one will crop up and be hard to stamp out.

## 1) What does your error log tell you?

[find out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8955482/3536236) where your log is stored and use it with [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) to output [custom messages](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

## 2) Stop using `isset()`

Frankly, [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is a terrible function because it's return values are not always logical for those not used to PHP's quirks. Don't use it. I feel `empty()` gives a more accurate result when judging the value of a variable.

Even better, be as specific as possible. If `$_SESSION['id']` is going to be a numeric value you can simply do this:

```
if((int)$_SESSION['id'] > 0 ){
    //stuff happens when a positive value of id is found.
}
```

Explanation:
The `(int)` casts the value to integer and then this is compared as to if it is above zero. Therefore *`false`* or *`null`* values are never false positives as they become `0`. Whereas `isset` would return **`true`** for ***`false`*** values.

## 3) Clean up your excess `;` .

You do not need them after `}` in any instance.

## 4) You're checking passwords WRONG.

You should be using [`password_hash()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash). You should be checking the database for the username, `SELECT`ing the corresponding [hashed] password and then checking if this value matches the hash of the `POST`ed input with [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Why [use `password_hash`](https://jonsuh.com/blog/securely-hash-passwords-with-php/)?

**Fix this. No excuses. This NEEDS to be fixed.**.

## 5) Stop wrapping your string variables in brackets.

It's not needed and can cause logic issues with dealing with functions (which should have brackets) issues as well as confuse reading the code for others.

## 6) When checking the same value multiple times use `switch` statements.

This is more efficient than a bunch of `if` statements as you're checking once and then seeing what the result matches.

```
switch ($membertype){
    case 1:
        $home = "/view/cook-dashboard.php";
        break;
    case 2:
        $home = "/view/customer-dashboard.php";
        break;
    case 3:
        $home = "/view/admin/dashboard.php";   
        break;
    default:
        $membertype = "xxx"; 
        $userID = 0;
   }
```

## 7) Stop creating wasted variables.

You have created the `$userID` variable but it's just the same as the $_SESSION['ID'] value, so what's the point of it? It add's a neatness possibly to your style of coding but your `else` value only ever resets the variable never the session.

Surely if you reach the `else` then you need to set `$_SESSION['ID'] = 0;` as well?

Excess and repetative variables are [wasted space, processing power and memory](http://blog.golemon.com/2007/01/youre-being-lied-to.html).

## 8) Look into using Prepared Statements with MySQLi

There are a lot of [almost](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/basic-usage-of-mysqli-with-prepared-statements-for-beginners.php) [decent tutorials](https://phpbestpractices.org/) on the net about using Prepared Statements. Explore it. There are also a [lot of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290975/how-to-create-a-secure-mysql-prepared-statement-in-php) [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988867/when-should-i-use-prepared-statements/24989031) about how to use Prepared Statements.

## 9) Stop using `SELECT *`

Specifically pick the [columns you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful). Saves energy, saves time.

## 10) Check your database!

- Is your column name correct? Names are case sensitive.
- Does other data from that same row get returned ok?
- Is there any data in that specific field to return?

## And finally......

## 11) Your issue needs to be explored.

try this:

```
while ($db_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login_result))
    {
    error_log("While loop run. Login Data found:\n");
    error_log(print_r($_db_result,true));

    $id = $db_result['id'];
    $membertype = $db_result['memberType'];
    ....
```

This will output telling you exactly if the column `memberType` has a value for the chosen row.

---

From the code you've shown I suspect that a) the excess `;` are causing logic hiccups. or b) that you're database data is not being output as expected.

---

Disclaimer: There are a couple of other more minor errors and symptomatic issues but I have to drawn the line somewhere.... Also many of the best practises I have shared *do* have specific situations where they may not apply.

Comment: I shall condider myself schooled. Seriously though, thanks a lot for taking the time to point these things out. I will 100% definitely take onboard the lessons here for the future. I do want to let you know that that I am hashing passwords. @Martin