# Where exactly can I check error logs for 500 error?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, server, phalcon

I just uploaded my changes to server which contains a functionality of sending email to the user but on sending email i get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` error in console. I am unable to trace the error, where can i find the exact error which caused this issue?

- I'm using Phalcon Framework
- Phalcon Version: **3.3.1**
- PHP Version: **5.6.33**
- Nginx

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out the error\_log's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955411/find-out-the-error-logs-path)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson please explain how is it duplicate?

Comment: If you find the error log, you will see what the error message actually is.

Comment: 1. 500 errors ends up in the configured error log. Looking at the error log should give you the information you need to find out what caused the error. 2. If the link didn't help you, just say that instead of being rude. That will _not_ help you... good luck. I'm out.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes it didn't help me and nor did your rude comments good bye!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Linux Systems**

```
/var/log/[SERVER NAME]/php_errors.log & errors.log

[SERVER NAME] is apache2 - if you are using apache or lampp - when you are using lampp
```

**In Windows System**

```
[SERVER SOURCE ROOT]/logs.

(P.S - This Paths are default configured paths check php.conf)
```

Answer (score 1):

It will depends on what OS your server is.

If we suppose it's a linux or unix server, you should be able to see them in /var/log/nginx/error.log if you didn't modify where the log are written in your vhost.

Answer (score 0):

**Also can check in:**

```
/usr/local/apps/apache/logs
```